# Html body overflow hidden with content scroll

Tags: html, css, overflow

I've got a css background animation set to overflow:hidden on the body tag (Codepen below).

```
body {
overflow: hidden;
}
```

I also have regular page content that I still need to scroll as usual.

The overflow:hidden on the body obviously prevents this.
Is there any way to retain a regular scroll on my page content?

https://codepen.io/lowercase01/pen/GRrzQxG

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/kohansalism/8xgry5k2/

Answer (score 1):

I have come up with a solution I think addresses the problem you are trying to solve.
Following is a summary of what I have done.
I have wrapped the `.background` div into what I've called the `.background-container`. I then have set the `.background-container` height to 0, removed the the `overflow:hidden` from the body and, then reordered the divs so that the `.wrapper` div comes last.

Here is a link to the codepen, https://codepen.io/zukomgwili/pen/GRrzQeY.

Comment: This solution almost works. The main issue is that I'd like the background animation to be hidden outside of a 100vh/100vw window. At the moment it still flows below the fold if that make s sense. Any way to contain the animation to the intitial window kind of like a background:fixed would achieve?

Comment: So if the user scrolls down past 100vh the animation should disappear or is it to stay fixed behind everything in a 100vw x 100vh size however far they scroll?

Answer (score 1):

How to hide scrollbar in browsers (Still scrollable)

```
/* Webkit */
::-webkit-scrollbar {
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
}

/* Firefox */
html {
  scrollbar-width: none;
}
```

Comment: Quick solution but I still need scrollbars to be visible.